# Tracking Full exit of application in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a very different scenario,

I am looking for the solution where if some one try to close the app forcefully I need to clear the sharedprefrences data before closing. So if user comes back to app, they need to relogin again
Any help will be appriciated.

Regards,
Nikhil

Answer (score -1):

On mobile system you should typically not behave differently depending on whether your application gets killed in the background or not. The user shouldn't be aware of application lifecycles, it's just a matter of the OS doing memory/battery management.

That being said. There are lifecycle hooks natively for iOS (`applicationWillTerminate` of `AppDelegate` and Android `onDestroy` of the `Application`). But at this time you probably don't expect your app to have enough time to asynchronously communicate with your flutter/dart code and back again, to do the cleanup you are asking for.

So I would suggest to take a good look at your use case. One way would be to use the `WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver` to listen for `didChangeAppLifecycleState` for the state changing to `AppLifecycleState.pause` and do your cleanup. So when the user switched away from your app and back again (no matter if the app was killed in the meantime) you can show a new login prompt.

There is an example in the [flutter documentation on how to add a observer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html).

```dart
class _AppLifecycleReactorState extends State<AppLifecycleReactor> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    // TODO check the new state.
  }
```